# Cakephp fail to return a value form child function to parent function

Tags: cakephp

I get an issue while return a value from recursive function, I have except return some value which I was return in another function, EX: If i was print a value in `test3` function it printed and also it's returns the parent function `test2` here also printed the return value, but when I print in main function `test1` it's not printed why it's behave like this?

I have tried this below code:

```
class TestController extends AppController {
   public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        ---------#code
   }
   public function test1(){
       $parm1 = $_POST['val1'];
       $parm2 = $_POST['val2'];
       $res = $this->test2($parm1,$parm2);
       pr($res);
   }
   private function test2($parm1,$parm2){
       #calculations
       if(condition){
           #$parm2 value increment
           $this->test2($parm1,$parm2);               
       }else{
           $valf =  $this->test3($parm1,$parm2);
           #here I print $valf it's printed but it's not return a value
           return $valf ;
       } 
   }
   private function test3($parm1,$parm2){
       #calculations
       if(condition){  
           $val = somevalue;
           return $val;
       }else{
           return false;
       } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should use `return` here:

```
   private function test2($parm1,$parm2){
       if(condition){
           return $this->test2($parm1,$parm2);  // Here             
       }else{
           $valf =  $this->test3($parm1,$parm2);
           return $valf ;
       } 
   }
```

By the way I think it's not "MVC-way" to perform recursive methods inside controller. In CakePHP You can use `Component`